# @font-face not working on ie7 and ie8

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I've got my @font-face styles written as follows:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Din';
  src: url('/fonts/DINWebPro.eot?') format('eot'),
       url('/fonts/DINWebPro.woff') format('woff');
```

}

It's working in every browser except IE7 and 8, anyone got any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use [fontsquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator)'s @font-face generator to generate all the fontfile types that you need, i think early IE like to use .svg font files (which you dont have).

fontsquirrel will take your font file, generate all the font files with other extensions from it and then give you them all along with a css file that shows you how to use them.

Using this method will ensure that your custom font works in all major browsers, even old IEs

Answer (score 0):

If you use the generator over at http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator you'll get a pretty decent result for embedding in every browser.

That being said, your problem consists of IE nuances.

> “...So what Paul has devised is a method of intercepting IE before it
>   arrives at “problematic” formats. Using the best kind of CSS hack (one
>   with no meaningless syntax), he diverts IE before it wastes bandwidth
>   grabbing an unnecessary file—and before it chokes.”

See `src: local("☺")` below

[Paul Irish](http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/) recommends the following:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Your typeface";
  src: url("type/filename.eot");
  src: local("☺"),
    url("type/filename.woff") format("woff"),
    url("type/filename.otf") format("opentype"),
    url("type/filename.svg#filename") format("svg");
  }
```

Note the smiley face is serious. It's html character `&#9786;`

There's also a [great summary](http://nicewebtype.com/notes/2009/10/30/how-to-use-css-font-face/) that lays out every step of the process.